# Shell script to run .ino code

Tags: shell, ubuntu, arduino

I have an `.ino` code named `lights.ino` to reprogram `Arduino` lights.

```
#include "FastSPI_LED2.h"
CRGB leds[NUM_LEDS];
byte serialData;

void setup() {
  delay(2000);
  LEDS.setBrightness(128);
  LEDS.addLeds<WS2801>(leds, NUM_LEDS);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  turnOff();
}

void glowOnce(){
    for(int scale = 0; scale < 128; scale++) {
      LEDS.showColor(CRGB(128, 128, 128), scale);
      delay(5);
    }

    for(int scale = 128; scale > 0; scale--) {
      LEDS.showColor(CRGB(128, 128, 128), scale);
      delay(5);
    }
}

void turnOn(){
    for(int scale = 0; scale < 128; scale++) {
      LEDS.showColor(CRGB(128, 128, 128), scale);
      delay(5);
    }
}
```

to run this I need to run `arduino` from command line and open file
from `tools` menu , then select "`Serial Monitor`" .
I need to run a shell script from python to this for me.
How can I write a shell script for these steps ?

Comment: Are you sure you wouldn't rather just run Ino and minicom, which not only being easier would also be *possible*?

Comment: Thanks @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams, could you plz help me with the command